# Какой знак препинания поставить? "Он чует (?) крадется, сгущается зверский холод"

Tags: пунктуация

Какой знак препинания поставить? Он чует (?) крадётся, сгущается зверский холод.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Это БСП с изъяснительным значением,** ставится двоеточие или тире.

(1) Он чует: крадётся, сгущается зверский холод.

(2) Он чует — крадётся, сгущается зверский холод.

**Выбор зависит от контекста.**

В случае двоеточия в большей степени выделено восприятие ситуации героем. Перед второй частью делается увеличенная **предупредительная пауза.**

При постановке тире первая часть воспринимается как вводная, главное внимание уделено самой ситуации.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=148#pp148

7. Перед второй частью бессоюзного сложного предложения ставится тире, если она (нередко — неполное предложение) имеет **изъяснительное значение** (перед ней можно вставить союз что), причем в первой части **не содержится интонационного предупреждения** о последующем изложении какого-либо факта: Овца же говорит — она всю ночь спала (Кр.);

Comment: В этом предложении ТИРЕ ставить не нужно: в первой части как раз СОДЕРЖИТСЯ интонационное предупреждение. Здесь возможно только двоеточие.

Comment: А как Вы понимаете интонационное предупреждение? У Вас есть определение или Вы можете описать вид интонации (движение тона, длительность паузы) при постановке тире и двоеточия, сравнить их между собой?  О чем предупреждает нас интонация и какой интонационный  элемент для этого конкретно используется?  Расскажите нам, пожалуйста, а я чуть позже сделаю то же самое.

Comment: Что касается Розенталя, то он говорит, что двоеточие ставится при наличии интонационного предупреждения, а тире при его отсутствии. Автор выбирает нужную ему интонацию по СМЫСЛУ и ставит знак, соответствующий этому выбору. Именно поэтому я в своем ответе остановилась на семантических особенностях обоих вариантов. И мне совершенно непонятна однозначность вашего выбора. С помощью интонации и соответствующего знака  препинания Вы  можете  обозначить разное прочтение текста. Этим знаки препинания похожи на  нотные знаки в музыке

Answer (score 3):

Двоеточие. Оно откроет содержание чуянья.